# How do I cast the results of a LINQ query against my custom object implicitly?

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, casting

I'm working on a project that uses lots of custom classes, each of which represents, effectively, a row of data from the database.  I've been doing this when there is more than one than one data element:

```
public class Client
{
    private int _clientID;
    private double _annualRevenue;

    public int ClientID
    {
        get { return _clientID; }
        set { _clientID = value; }
    }

    public double AnnualRevenue
    {
        get { return _annualRevenue; }
        set { _annualRevenue = value; }
    }
}
```

And then, elsewhere in the code...

```
public class QueryClients
{

    private List<Client> _clients;

    public List<Client> FindClientByRevenue(double minimumRevenue)
    {
        List<Client> returnValue = (from c in _clients
                                    where c.AnnualRevenue >= minimumRevenue
                                    select c).ToList();

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

This works fine, but IMHO it's ugly to have to keep declaring this list like this everywhere else in the code.  I'm going to have to use this in at least 100 different places.  I'd like to clean it up by creating a custom class to simply represent that List, using a meaningful name.  What I mean is something LIKE this:

```
public class Clients : List<Client> { }
```

Now this works, but the results of that LINQ query will not cast to it IMPLICITLY. So bear with me.  If the new code looks like this...

```
public class QueryClients
{

    private Clients _clients;

    public QueryClients(Clients clients)
    {
        _clients = clients;
    }

    public Clients FindClientByRevenue(double minimumRevenue)
    {
        Clients returnValue = (from c in _clients
                                    where c.AnnualRevenue >= minimumRevenue
                                    select c).ToList();

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

...I get a compiler error:

```
CS0266
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Client>' to 'Clients'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Okay, okay, so I can disappear this compiler error in the IDE by EXPLICITLY casting the result of the LINQ query:

```
public class QueryClients
{

    private Clients _clients;

    public QueryClients(Clients clients)
    {
        _clients = clients;
    }

    public Clients FindClientByRevenue(double minimumRevenue)
    {
        Clients returnValue = (Clients)(from c in _clients
                                        where c.AnnualRevenue >= minimumRevenue
                                        select c).ToList();

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

The code even compiles fine.  But as soon as I hit that query, it blows up.

```
        Clients clients = new Clients();
        Client client;

        client = new Client();
        client.ClientID = 1;
        client.AnnualRevenue = 100;
        clients.Add(client);

        client = new Client();
        client.ClientID = 2;
        client.AnnualRevenue = 200;
        clients.Add(client);

        client = new Client();
        client.ClientID = 3;
        client.AnnualRevenue = 300;
        clients.Add(client);

        QueryClients q = new QueryClients(clients);

        Clients clients2 = q.FindClientByRevenue(200);
```

Of course, it's a casting error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred.

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Client]' to type 'Clients'.
```

So even though it compiles, it won't RUN, and even if this approach DID WORK, it doesn't really solve my problem because then I'd have to explicitly cast the results of every LINQ query and if I have to do that I might as well just declare lists everywhere.  Sigh.

So anyway, I'm doing something wrong, and I just can't see how to do fix it.  I'm sure that, at minimum, I need to add a conversion/casting operator of some sort to my Clients class to allow an implicit conversion to happen (or something).  I've tried numerous different things based on numerous different Google searches and it either won't compile or it won't run.  I just can't figure it out.

There are two goals:

1.)  Use a Clients object in my code rather than having to declare a list variable over and over.

2.)  Be able to run a LINQ query to select some Client object(s) from one Clients object into another (new) Clients object.

Is this possible?  Can you actually show me how to modify the Clients class so it will work (casting implicitly)?  If it can be done, I'm sure it's simple and I'll kick myself for not having seen it myself before posting.

Thanks in advance for the insight.

Comment: Simple: Use `List<Client>` (and use `IEnumerable<Client>` where appropriate). Don't waste your time on crazy stunts to avoid using angle brackets *at the expense of readability* even if you could get it to work. Your time would be more profitably spent smoking weed than writing this code.

Comment: Why is it ugly? It's just generics. You will have more mileage by getting used to the syntax. Personally I would rather know that the variable is `IEnumerable<Client>` than `Clients`.

Comment: Use `var` where possible. The idea of generics is to *reduce* the number of classes you need. You essentially want to return to .Net 1.

Comment: In my opinion, using a type name like this makes the code MORE readable, but I've always been the king of crazy stunts.  I've now wasted 2 days on this, I guess.   :(    Since everybody here agrees that using brackets everywhere is the answer, guess I better just go that route.

Comment: @MorganLeppink `Client` is easily distinguishable from `List<Client>` or `IEnumerable<Client>`. `Client` and `Clients` look very  much the same. Anybody who is familiar with .NET code expects "one foo" to look like `foo` and "sequence of foo" to look like `IWhatever<foo>`. I use "readable" to mean "I can go straight to thinking about the intent without puzzling over the identifiers or the syntax". What does it mean to you?

Comment: @MorganLeppink If you spent two days on this, I think it's likely you have a mistaken mental model of what type casting means in C#. It should have been instantly obvious to you that you can't cast a class to a subclass of itself. The two days would've been better spent reading up on type casting, and probably the type system in general, value vs reference types and so on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get a cast exception because the dynamic type of the result of the list query is `List<Client>` and not Clients which inherits from it (You can't cast from an 'Animal' to a 'Dog' when the object is not actually a 'Dog').

Since you cannot have any user defined conversions from a base class I would suggest removing the inheritance and adding an implicit (or explicit cast):

```
public class Clients {
    private List<Client> d;

    public Clients(List<Client> d)
    {
        this.d = d.ToList();
    }

    public static implicit operator Clients(List<Client> d)
    {
        return new Clients(d);
    }
}
```

This however will not allow you to treat Clients as an Enumerable. Alternatively you may write an extension method to `IEnumerable<Client>` with the following signature:

```
  public static Clients ToClientList(this IEnumerable<Client> input){
     return new Clients(input);
  }
```

As a side note, I think that using a `List<Client>` is more elegant and clear than defining your own class..

Comment: Perfect, looks like I'm sticking with angle brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize but changing this:

```
public class QueryClients
{
    private List<Client> _clients;

    public List<Client> FindClientByRevenue(double minimumRevenue)
    {
        List<Client> returnValue = (from c in _clients
                                where c.AnnualRevenue >= minimumRevenue
                                select c).ToList();

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public class QueryClients
{
    private Clients _clients;

    public List<Client> FindClientByRevenue(double minimumRevenue)
    {
        Clients returnValue = (from c in _clients
                                where c.AnnualRevenue >= minimumRevenue
                                select c).ToList();

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

make no sense.
You expecting using type `Clients` in exactly same way as `List<Client>`.
So seems better if you continue using `List<Client>` with all benefit generic `List` can have.

Comment: Sticking with angle brackets, I guess.   Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat: Don't do this, stick with `List<Client>`, but for educational reasons below is the answer*

---

You have a number of options, first is to simply have your Class take as a constructor argument the `IEnumerable<Client>`

```
public class Clients : List<Client>
{
    public Clients(IEnumerable<Client> clients) 
        : base(clients){}
}
```

And then as your query

```
Clients returnValue = new Clients(from c in _clients
                                    where c.AnnualRevenue >= minimumRevenue
                                    select c);
```

---

Another is to provide an explicit cast to do much the same from `IList<Client>` but you'll have to change your `Clients` class to not inherit `List<Client>`.

```
public class Clients 
{
    private  List<Client> list;
    public Clients(IEnumerable<Client> clients) 
    { this.list = clients.ToList(); }

    public static explicit operator Clients(List<Client> list)
    {
          return new Clients(list);
    }
}
```

This would allow something like your original code

```
 Clients returnValue = (Clients)(from c in _clients
                                    where c.AnnualRevenue >= minimumRevenue
                                    select c).ToList();
```

Comment: In the cast sample, aren't you getting :
user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed

Comment: This doesn't work as well -  user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You should create a .dbml file that links to your database on which you can add all the SQL tables for which you want a model class to query your database. This will also generate the class automatically without writing a single line of code. After that you can modify a instance of this model you queried from the database and submit your changes. Not a single SQL query to write to update or delete. Everything is handled by LINQ.

Here's a good walkthrough:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx

Once everything is setup all you have to do is:
// Create your DataContext

MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext(myConnectionString)

// Query some Clients - The Client class would be generated automatically by LINQ

List < Client > clients = (from client in context.Clients where CONDITON select client).ToList()

// Modify those clients as you wish 
// Submit changes to the data context (will automatically update modified class from this data context)

context.SubmitChanges()